# How to create a function that creates N(numbers) of objects with a N properties?

Tags: javascript, go

I'm trying to make a function in JS, also in Go, to make N objects with N properties.

I want a function that returns N objects with N properties. So for I got this:

```
function objects(name, age, idioms,school) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.idioms= idioms;
    this.school = school;
}
```

I don't even know how to do this in Go.

Comment: Use a `map[string]interface{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an simple example with `maps` in golang. You can also use a similar logic with using `structs` with fixed props. The function takes an int value N, and a string array which are the props.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func createDynamicMap(n int, pr []string) ([]map[string]interface{}) {
    var listOfMap []map[string]interface{}
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        dm := make(map[string]interface{})
        for _, v := range pr {
            if _, ok := dm[v]; !ok {
                dm[v] = nil // all props initialised as nil
            }
        }
        listOfMap = append(listOfMap, dm)
    }
    return listOfMap
}

func main() {
    dynamicMap := createDynamicMap(10,[]string{"name","age","gender"})
    fmt.Println(len(dynamicMap))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the Golang part, but for the JavaScript you'd be better off making new object instances from [a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Create the class, and then pass in objects the properties of which you [can loop over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and instantiate in the new class instance.

```js
class Creator { 

  // args can be an object with n amount of
  // properties
  constructor(args) {

    // Just loop over the entries and assign each value
    // to the instance
    Object.entries(args).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      this[key] = value;
    });
  };
}

const obj = { name: 'Bob', age: 2, idioms: 'etc', school: 'Grange Hill' };
const obj2 = { name: 'Steve', job: 'Farmer' };

console.log(new Creator(obj));
console.log(new Creator(obj2));
```